# firing an event on load and if the textbox has value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a textbox like this on a page/tab.

```
<input id="number" ng-model="model.number" ng-change="ChangeValue()"/>
```

Now on change of value, it fires the function. However, on page load when the textbox retrieves the saved value in DB, it is not firing this event. I want that on page load, if model.number has a value i.e whenever the textbox has the value, fire the event.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you stop adding `angular2` tag if it's AngularJS 1.x only? Thanks.

Comment: @HarryNinh: Sure but I was understanding angular 2 folks already might know an answer to this

Comment: @Learner has nothing to do with who might know it...you only tag what is relevant in the code problem

Comment: Stop with the *"how to achieve this"* type questions. Here we go again with another code problem of yours that doesn't include a [mcve]. You should know by now that the idea of this site is to provide enough code to represent a reproduceable problem, not snippets and general questions

Comment: @charlietfl: Sorry I am after a suggestion for a simple scenario. My scenario is, when the textbox has any value on load, it should trigger a function.  Do you know how to implement this?

Comment: Not if you don't show us the function code, the data retrieval code and provide a proper explanation of what the exact problem is and what the expected behavior is. You are oversimplifying what should be presented for people to fully comprehend your issues

Comment: Also sounds like a simple `if` statement and call the function. Beyond that how else can we answer with no code to work from

Comment: @charlietfl: sorry you are being so offensive and rude, I am so innocent and learning :( Please dont be harsh, I do agree with your thoughts

Comment: I am not being rude...I am trying to point out a repeating pattern where you don't provide enough details in your questions. Your question history is full of this pattern. Nothing wrong with learning but learn to use the site properly and you will get far better and quicker responses...and we don't have to do near as much guessing to figure them out. You need to help us help you. As it stands now you haven't provided enough detail for people to help properly

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angular documentation for ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> It will not be evaluated if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value

From your description, the model is being programmatically changed. Therefore, ngChange will not fire. If you want ChangeValue to run on page load, you need to explicitly call it.

Hope this helps.